# EC2 AMIs, Volumes, Snapshots. which of these are changed a fee by AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2

After 3 years on AWS cloud, I have many AMIs, volumes, and snapshots.

Does AWS charge money for my AMIs, volumes, and snapshots?

How to identify those that are not associated with active instances to delete? I have found no way to associate an AMI to an instance and I am afraid to accidentally delete an AMI and cause an instance to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete an AMI without affecting any instance that was launched from it.  You just won't be able to launch any new ones, since the AMI no longer exists.

There isn't s charge for the AMI itself, but each AMI is backed by at least one snapshot, and all snapshots are billable.

You can delete any snapshot that you don't need.  It it's associated with an AMI, the system should prevent the deletion.  Deleting snapshots does not affect instances with volumes created from the snapshots.

Snapshots are incremental, but this is transparent.  If you have multiple snapshots of the same volume, you can delete any snapshots you don't need without affecting the others (even though they are incremental).  Let's say it's a 100 GiB volume and you have 3 snapshots, A, B, and C.  Between snapshots A and B, only 10 GiB of data changed, and between snapshots B and C, only 40 GiB of data changed.  You have 300 GiB of snapshots, but you're only being billed for 150 GiB (100 + 10 + 40).  If you delete snapshot B, any blocks that were unchanged from B to C are still available because they are associated with snapshots B and C both.  Delete B, and C is not affected.  You will no longer be billed for any backup blocks for data that isn't needed by either A or C, so the charge may go down, but not a lot, since you freed, maximum, 10 GiB of backup storage (snapshot B only had 10 GiB that differed from A, but some of that may still be needed for C).

All volumes are billable.  Deleting an unused volume will not impact any snapshots that were made from that volume.

You may want to review your detail billing to see what these things are costing you, remembering that the total charge for snapshot storage will almost always be smaller than the total size of all your snapshots.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like if I only care about the latest instance data, I can delete all snapshots except the latest one. Then the size of snapshot charged should be the same as my volume size. 100 GiB in your example.